# Get a return value with cURL between two websites

Tags: php, curl

I've two websites and I can transfer strings with cURL from website one to website two. All fine.

But now I want to transfer a security key from website one to website two and check in website two if the key is in the database of website two.

If yes -> return true

If no -> return false

That is my code:
This code transfer the key string with cURL to the other website.

```
function dmd_check_key($arg){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.de/link/key_generator.php?key='.$arg.'',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
return $resp;
}
```

This code is in website two and check if the security key is in the database.

```
function dmd_key_check($key){
    if(isset($_GET['key'])){
        // Initialize
        $database = new medoo([
                'database_type' => 'mysql',
                'database_name' => 'xxx',
                'server' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'xxx',
                'password' => 'xxx',
                'charset' => 'utf8'
        ]); 

        $datas = $database->select("keys", [
                "dmd_key",
                "id"
        ], [
                "dmd_key[=]" => $key
        ]); 

    if($datas[0]['dmd_key'] == $key){
        print 'true';
    }else{
        print 'false';
    }
    }
}
```

You can see the last if-clause. If the key string is equal the string in the database set return true.. if not.. return false.

Now my question is.
How can I get the return value from website two?

Here my AJAX form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //click event fï¿½r submit button
  jQuery('.dmd_admin_buttons').click(function () {

  //Daten von den HTML Feldern in JS-Vars ï¿½bersetzen
  var post = jQuery('input[name=post]');
  var page = jQuery('input[name=page]');
  var searchbox = jQuery('input[name=searchbox]');
  var formidable = jQuery('input[name=formidable]');
  var key = jQuery('input[name=key]');

  if ( jQuery( post ).prop( "checked" ) )
      post.val(1); 
  else
      post.val(0);

 if ( jQuery( page ).prop( "checked" ) )
     page.val(1);
 else
     page.val(0);

  if ( jQuery( searchbox ).prop( "checked" ) )
     searchbox.val(1);
 else
     searchbox.val(0);

  if ( jQuery( formidable ).prop( "checked" ) )
     formidable.val(1);
 else
     formidable.val(0);     

  var data = 'post=' + post.val() + '&page=' + page.val() + '&searchbox=' + searchbox.val() + '&formidable=' + formidable.val() + '&key=' + key.val();

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo plugins_url( 'saveData.php', __FILE__ ); ?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: just replace return with print 'true'  or print 'false' ,,,, then in the first site check the $resp ,, it must be true string or false string

Comment: what you get by alert ??

Comment: false or true I got back.

Comment: great to know you solved it

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

website two should print a strings like

```
function dmd_key_check($key){
    if(isset($_GET['key'])){
        // Initialize
        $database = new medoo([
                'database_type' => 'mysql',
                'database_name' => 'xxx',
                'server' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'xxx',
                'password' => 'xxx',
                'charset' => 'utf8'
        ]); 

        $datas = $database->select("keys", [
                "dmd_key",
                "id"
        ], [
                "dmd_key[=]" => $key
        ]); 

        if($datas[0]['dmd_key'] == $key){
            print json_encode(array('status'=>true));
        }else{
            print json_encode(array('status'=>false));
        } 
    }
}
```

website one should check $resp

```
function dmd_check_key($arg){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.de/link/key_generator.php?key='.$arg.'',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $resp = json_decode($resp);
    if($resp['status'] == 'true'){
         //do some thing for true
    }else{
         //do some thing for false
    }

}
```

Comment: If I include your if-clause into my dmd_check_key function my form to check the key string runs into in error.

Comment: pls first var_dump($resp) to check what you get maybe i am wrong.. just check the returned value

Comment: Same issue. If I include a var_dump I got an error.

Comment: remove my  if-clause and just type the var_dump then tell me what the error you faced

Comment: I see my problem! I use my form with ajax.. If I turn off ajax it works. But that isn't a good solution for me.

Comment: so it is easy .. from your ajax you can check the returned value  .. share us your ajax also to help you

Comment: Ok I have it! I added this into my ajax form:         success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88094/discussion-between-mohammad-alabed-and-cgee).